# How to Get attributes list from ArrayList of objects

Tags: java, arraylist

Suppose I have an object that looks like:

```
public class Obj {
String foo;
String bar;
}
```

If I create an arraylist of type Obj and populate it, is there a way I can return a list of all the objects in the array's foo attribute from the ArrayList?

EDIT:  I should have been more clear, I did not want to do this via iteration

Comment: You have List<Obj> objs and want to create a second list from that List<String> that contains the foo attribute of all the Obj from objs?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You'll have to iterate through your `List<Obj>` and collate the foo entries into a new `List`

e.g.

```
List<String> foos = new ArrayList<String>();
for (Obj obj : objs) {
  foos.add(obj.foo)
}
```

or for Java 8 and beyond, use streams thus:

```
objs.stream().map(o -> o.foo).collect(toList());
```

Comment: my first version was goign to be this:  `var foos = objs.Select( x=>x.foo);` until i realized it was a java question.  Damn you `LINQ` goodness!

Comment: You can do the equivalent of `map` in plain Java using something like Guava. There's (a bit) more work involved obviously, but it has advantages over allocating memory for a copy of all the `foo` values in the original list.

Comment: Does Java 8 Lambda provide any new cleverness for this? Ala the scala-LINQ trickery.

Answer (score 10):

Try this:

```
Collection<String> names = CollectionUtils.collect(personList, TransformerUtils.invokerTransformer("getName"));
```

Use apache commons collection api.

Answer (score 4):

Using [Guava](http://guava-libraries.googlecode.com) you could create a view of the `foo` property of the objects in the `List` using [Lists.transform](http://guava-libraries.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/javadoc/com/google/common/collect/Lists.html#transform%28java.util.List,%20com.google.common.base.Function%29) like this:

```
public class Obj {
  String foo;
  String bar;

  public static final Function<Obj, String> FOO = new Function<Obj, String>() {
    public String apply(Obj input) {
      return input.foo;
    }
  };
}

public void someMethod(List<Obj> objs) {
  List<String> foos = Lists.transform(objs, Obj.FOO);
  ...
}
```

Unlike other solutions, this is purely a *view* of the `List<Obj>` and as such it doesn't allocate a whole separate `ArrayList` or some such in memory and can be created in almost no time regardless of the size of your `List<Obj>`. Additionally, if you change the original `List<Obj>`, the `foos` list will reflect that change.

In Java 8 (due in 2012 sometime), this will become a lot easier with lambda expressions and method references. You'll be able to do something like this:

```
List<Obj> objs = ...
List<String> foos = objs.map(#Obj.getFoo);
```

Answer (score 1):

The answer of @Surodip uses a compact solution based on [Apache Commons Collections](https://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-collections/).
But that solution is not typesafe, since the Transfomer references the property via string expression: `TransformerUtils.invokerTransformer("getName")`

Here is a more verbose, but typesafe solution using Apache Commons Collections:

```
Collection<String> values = CollectionUtils.collect(messages, new Transformer<Obj, String>(){

            @Override
            public String transform(Obj input) {
                return input.getFoo();
            }

        });
```

The above solutions uses Apache Commons Collection Version >= 4, which supports generics for type safety.

Below is the less typesafe version for Apache Collections Version < 4, which does not use generics:

```
Collection values = CollectionUtils.collect(messages, new Transformer(){

            @Override
            public Object transform(Object input) {
                Obj obj = (Obj) input;
                return obj.getFoo();
            }

        });
```

Answer (score 0):

Iterate through the list and create a Set of all foo properties.

Answer (score 0):

something like this?

```
List<String> foos = new ArrayList<String>();
for (Obj obj : objList )
{
    foos.addElement(obj.foo);
}
```